# How to know the page where an element can be find?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL and Php.

Here's the thing : I'm building a forum, with topics and posts.

Posts are displayed in a topic in different pages (let's say 10 posts/page).

My question is : if I ask to see a specific post in a topic, how can I know the page where the post is displayed ? (With the purpose to display the page required)

Should I calculate the number of pages then check each group of items of all possible pages or something like that ?

Thx for your help !

Comment: Answer to this question greatly depends on how you build your forum's structure. Build out your database structure and share it with us so we don't have to guess on how it is built (post results of `describe {table_name}` )

Comment: @Dimi : done ! ^^

Comment: Are you writing the code of your forum? If yes, just save the page number when the post is inserted. If some post can be removed, just update the page number of others posts. You can't calculate it at runtime, it's so much expensive. The "google way" doesn't know nothing about your database, it only saves the page result (link) with the text converted to lexemes.

Comment: Thx you guys, I figured out a way of how to do it (see my answer below) !

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google Custom Search and let Google do all the hard work. I hear they're quite good for searching websites.

If you want something a little fancier you can pay for Google Site Search.

if your site is small and you want to try a really really simple solution why don't you explore MySQL Fulltext search?

That said the field, fields to search must be a Fulltext index. So you can grab a pair of text fields and some varchar fields and jointhem all in a Fulltex Index.

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('database' WITH QUERY EXPANSION);
```

But go and have a better look at MySQL manual!

Comment: Ok... It's with answers like that I see I'm a real noob (and english is hard for me). I understood quite nothing of your answer xD. What is the link with a Google tool ? I'm trying to calculate the page where the post is to display this specific page.... Hope I'm understandable ^^

Comment: In an other way, it could be : I have 150 items in a table, how can I know the position of a specific one in MySQL (with a specific ordering, etc) ?

Comment: i am sorry for the trouble. i think you need to find the page number for the specific item isn't it?

Comment: "SELECT myRowSerial, FLOOR((myRowSerial-1)/10) AS pageNumber "  here myRow Serial is the row number of your item .I think it may help you.

Comment: Thx you guys, I figured out a way of how to do it (see my answer below) !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was eating and then... **THE IDEA**.

I guess a simple way to doing this is to count the number of items before the needed one (with ID or, in a better way, with Timestamps cause posts are ordered with those), and then calculate how many pages it takes.

Meaning, for example, if pages display 10 items, we have 24 items before our targeted one : `ceil(24/10) = 3` item will be in page 3 !
Very simple when we think of it.

```
#Get the page displaying the selected item

#Step 1 : calculate how many items are before the selected one
$nbr_of_items = SELECT COUNT(post_id) FROM posts WHERE post_topic_id = :topic_id AND post_timestamp < :timestamp_of_selected_item

#Step 2 : do simple maths
$calcul = ceil($nbr_of_items / $nbr_of_items_displayed_in_a_page);
For example, we have 24 items before the selected one and pages display 10 items :
$calcul = ceil(24 / 10) = 3
```

Of course it could be updated (what if an other post has the same timestamp, etc) but it's a good start.